# How to use the strsplit function with a period

Tags: r, strsplit

I would like to split the following string by its periods. I tried `strsplit()` with `"."` in the `split` argument, but did not get the result I want.

```
s <- "I.want.to.split"
strsplit(s, ".")
[[1]]
 [1] "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
```

The output I want is to split `s` into 4 elements in a list, as follows.

```
[[1]]
[1] "I"     "want"  "to"    "split"
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 54):

When using a regular expression in the `split` argument of `strsplit()`, you've got to escape the `.` with `\\.`, or use a charclass `[.]`.  Otherwise  you use `.` as its special character meaning, "any single character".

```
s <- "I.want.to.split"
strsplit(s, "[.]")
# [[1]]
# [1] "I"     "want"  "to"    "split"
```

But the more efficient method here is to use the `fixed` argument in `strsplit()`.  Using this argument will bypass the regex engine and search for an exact match of `"."`.

```
strsplit(s, ".", fixed = TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "I"     "want"  "to"    "split"
```

And of course, you can see `help(strsplit)` for more.

Answer (score 5):

You need to either place the dot `.` inside of a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) or precede it with two backslashes to escape it since the dot is a character of [special meaning](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) in regex meaning "match any single character (except newline)"

```
s <- 'I.want.to.split'
strsplit(s, '\\.')
# [[1]]
# [1] "I"     "want"  "to"    "split"
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides `strsplit()`, you can also use `scan()`. Try:

```
scan(what = "", text = s, sep = ".")
# Read 4 items
# [1] "I"     "want"  "to"    "split"
```