# "Warning: too many (few) values" for using tidyr packages in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I have the following data set `D7`

```
name sex_age eye_color height
1    J    M.34     Other     61
2    A    F.55      Blue     59
3    T    M.76     Brown     51
4    D    F.19     Other     57
```

I want to separate the column `sex_age` into `sex` column and `age` column, so I type

```
separate(D7,sex_age,c('sex','age'),sep='.')
```

But it generates

```
name sex age eye_color height
1    J             Other     61
2    A              Blue     59
3    T             Brown     51
4    D             Other     57
Warning message:
Too many values at 4 locations: 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Also, when I modify my original data set `D7` into `D8`

```
name sex_age eye_color height
1    J    M_34     Other     61
2    A    F_55      Blue     59
3    T    M_76     Brown     51
4    D    F_19     Other     57
```

And I type `D7 %>% separate(sex_age,c('sex','age'),sep="_")` it gives

```
name  sex  age eye_color height
1    J M.34 <NA>     Other     61
2    A F.55 <NA>      Blue     59
3    T M.76 <NA>     Brown     51
4    D F.19 <NA>     Other     57
Warning message:
Too few values at 4 locations: 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Did I misuse the `separate` function? I am very puzzled. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665100/how-to-use-the-strsplit-function-with-a-period

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since `sep=` argument considers regex and `.` is a special character, therefore we need to have `\\` before such special characters such that they are read as normal characters

```
separate(df, sex_age, into = c("sex", "age"), sep = "\\.")
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to regular expressions, learning it now.

Comment: But what about the warning generated by `_`? I wasn't aware that `_` had a special meaning in regex. Even adding `\\\` doesn't get rid of the warning.